# How to compare a string with a short string literal effectively

Tags: c, string, compare

If I don't want the overhead needed for a call to strcmp, I compare strings with short string literals the way described in the following code example:

```
#ifdef LITTLE_ENDIAN        //little-endian-addressing
#define BytesAsDWord_M(a, b, c, d)\
  ((ulong) ((a) | ((b) << 8) | ((ulong) (c) << 16) | ((ulong) (d) << 24)))

#define BytesAsWord_M(a, b)((ushort) ((a) | ((b) << 8)))

#else //LITTLE_ENDIAN       //little-endian-addressing
#define BytesAsDWord_M(a, b, c, d)\
 ((ulong) ((d) | ((c) << 8) | ((b) << 16) | ((a) << 24)))

#define BytesAsWord_M(a, b) ((ushort) ((b) | ((a) << 8)))
#endif //LITTLE_ENDIAN      //little-endian-addressing

bool AbsCompare(char* chr_p)
//compare string with  "abs"
{
  if (*((ulong*) &chr_p[1]) ==
    BytesAsDWord_M('a', 'b', 's', '\0'))
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

gcc compiles this example as long as I compile without optimization options enabled.
With optimization enabled I get the warning:

"dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules"

Even optimizing with -O3 doesn't result in effective code as the example illustrates:

```
//abstest.c

#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned long ulong;
typedef unsigned short ushort;

#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN     //little-endian-addressing
#define BytesAsDWord_M(a, b, c, d)\
  ((ulong) ((a) | ((b) << 8) | ((ulong) (c) << 16) | ((ulong) (d) << 24)))

#define BytesAsWord_M(a, b)((ushort) ((a) | ((b) << 8)))

#else //BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN //little-endian-addressing
#define BytesAsDWord_M(a, b, c, d)\
 ((ulong) ((d) | ((c) << 8) | ((b) << 16) | ((a) << 24)))

#define BytesAsWord_M(a, b) ((ushort) ((b) | ((a) << 8)))
#endif //BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN    //little-endian-addressing

int AbsCompare1(char* chr_p)
{
  return *(ulong*) chr_p ==  BytesAsDWord_M('a', 'b', 's', '\0');
}

int AbsCompare2(char* chr_p)
{
  return strcmp(chr_p, "abs");
}

int main(int argc __attribute__((unused)), char ** argv)
{
  int i;
  int j;

  i = AbsCompare1(argv[0]);
  j = AbsCompare2(argv[0]);

  return i + j;
}
```

objdump -d -Mintel abstest:

```
080483d0 <AbsCompare1>:
 80483d0:   55                      push   ebp
 80483d1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 80483d3:   8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 80483d6:   5d                      pop    ebp
 80483d7:   81 38 61 62 73 00       cmp    DWORD PTR [eax],0x736261
 80483dd:   0f 94 c0                sete   al
 80483e0:   0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
 80483e3:   c3                      ret    

080483f0 <AbsCompare2>:
 80483f0:   55                      push   ebp
 80483f1:   0f b6 0d 5c 85 04 08    movzx  ecx,BYTE PTR ds:0x804855c
 80483f8:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 80483fa:   8b 55 08                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 80483fd:   0f b6 02                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [edx]
 8048400:   29 c8                   sub    eax,ecx
 8048402:   75 2b                   jne    804842f <AbsCompare2+0x3f>
 8048404:   0f b6 42 01             movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [edx+0x1]
 8048408:   0f b6 0d 5d 85 04 08    movzx  ecx,BYTE PTR ds:0x804855d
 804840f:   29 c8                   sub    eax,ecx
 8048411:   75 1c                   jne    804842f <AbsCompare2+0x3f>
 8048413:   0f b6 42 02             movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [edx+0x2]
 8048417:   0f b6 0d 5e 85 04 08    movzx  ecx,BYTE PTR ds:0x804855e
 804841e:   29 c8                   sub    eax,ecx
 8048420:   75 0d                   jne    804842f <AbsCompare2+0x3f>
 8048422:   0f b6 42 03             movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [edx+0x3]
 8048426:   0f b6 15 5f 85 04 08    movzx  edx,BYTE PTR ds:0x804855f
 804842d:   29 d0                   sub    eax,edx
 804842f:   5d                      pop    ebp
 8048430:   c3                      ret
```

Is there a possibility to compare this short literal directly without the detour of embedding chr_p into a union, especially because I want to compare chr_p at arbitrary indices like "&chr_p[1]"?

Comment: I see that you're targeting both big- and little-endian architectures, but not taking into account possible alignment issues. An expression like `&chr_p[1]` is almost certainly going to evaluate to a non-word aligned address at some point.

Comment: ...what only would be a performance restriction as far as I know.

Comment: @Wosh On some architectures misaligned access will result in a hardware exception.

Comment: may I kindly suggest using a simple profiler to prove that your code does actually perform better than strcmp (or strncmp)? otherwise, nothing you can do will be of any measurable value to your program, except an awful mess of obfuscation ;)

Comment: @Andreas It's rather obvious that the 16 bytes of code for the comparision in example 1 are more effective than the at most 62 bytes in example 2.

Answer (score 9):

No there is not. Are you aware that a compiler will use its knowledge about `strcmp`? It will do exactly what you like to achieve (removing the call overhead) without having to resort to type-punning in the source. These kind of code transformations are most often done in a code generator after the compiler has taken all the benefit from alias analysis.

If I use `gcc -O3` to compile the following program, there is no call to `strcmp` to be found.

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        return strcmp(argv[0], "abs");
}
```

My x86 assembly for example looked like this (gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)) (I know it's old):

```
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx
        andl    $-16, %esp
        pushl   -4(%ecx)
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        pushl   %ecx
        movl    4(%ecx), %eax
        movl    (%eax), %edx
        movzbl  (%edx), %eax
        subl    $97, %eax
        jne     .L2
        movzbl  1(%edx), %eax
        subl    $98, %eax
        jne     .L2
        movzbl  2(%edx), %eax
        subl    $115, %eax
        jne     .L2
        movzbl  3(%edx), %eax
.L2:
        popl    %ecx
        popl    %ebp
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
        ret
```

Basically `strcmp` has been inlined and unrolled. Of course it highly depends on the code generator for your target. So if it is not evolved enough yet, then it may still generate a `strcmp`. Still makes you wonder if you should burden yourself with ugly code, if maybe the code generator will support this later .. when you are still stuck with your code.

Comment: What code do you get then? My `gcc -O3 -S` generates a tail-call to `strcmp()`.

Comment: @Pascal: I, for one, get a `repe cmpsb` instruction (with attendant setup and finalization). That's with GCC 4.7.2 targeting x86.

Comment: Just tested this, got an unrolled series of `jne` tests too, for each character of "abs" with GCC 4.7.2 for x86. Interestingly enough, compiling the same code as C++ yielded a `repz cmpsb`.